# Steam Signing Me Out Randomly

Tags: steam

Every time I start up Steam on my Apple Mac it signs me out and I have to log in. The problem here is I have steam guard on my phone. It's usually uncharged, but the bad thing is my phone has been shattered and I am awaiting a new screen for it. The phone obviously can't be charged so:

1. Is there a way to keep signed in?
2. How can I log in right now?

I have tried turning off Steam guard but it requires lots of stuff I cannot remember and just do not have access to.

Comment: If you do not remember your security information nor have access to it then you are out of luck. This is not really anything we can bypass here. You would have better luck contacting Steam support.

Comment: If you are able to log in then go to settings and there will be a check box that says *"Don't save account credentials on this computer"*. Leave it unchecked as it is by default. I'm not 100% positive but it may keep you logged in.

Comment: Same issue here, buggy as hell. Am signed in on some pages while am signed out as I navigate to other. It's completely random and annoys me as I need to sign in multiple times to buy a game. (happens for me on the website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you exit Steam before turning off your PC? Does your internet go out often and you turn it off? Do you leave your computer on or on standby when  you're not using it? Things like things would help us fix your problem.

Steam has never signed me out, so I cant help very much in proposing an immediate solution, but the only reasons why you'd have to re-sign in to my understanding, would be if you change your password or got a new authenticator.

If that is the issue, I would recommend disabling your authenticator if you can, or not using it until you get a new phone.

Comment: If you regularly log on to Steam from 2 or more different computers, then it will ask you to re-sign in when you switch between PCs..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would help but try downloading an emulator, making the steam guard app usable on PC. Of course this defeats the purpose of making it secure but at least you could access your steam while you get your phone fixed ;)

Here's a guide:

Step 1. Download BlueStacks (or any other pc android emulator) app on your PC http://www.bluestacks.com

Step 2. Install it

Step 3. go to http://store.steampowered.com/mobile and download ''Android users without access to Google Play can download version 2.1.3 here.'' which you will install on BlueStacks http://media.steampowered.com/apps/steam-android/steam-2.1.3.apk

Step 4. Change your settings.

[image]